# Materialize Collapsible Nav Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm not entirely sure why my collapsible dropdown menus are not working. I have imported materialize and jQuery and they are both working but the collapsible menu does nothing when clicked.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Create</title>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/materialize.css">
    <script src="js/materialize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
        .panel {
        height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col m10 panel cyan">
        </div>
        <div class="col m2 panel">
            <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="expandable">
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">extension</i>Objects</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">color_lens</i>Colors</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">create</i>Create</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></div>
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">collections</i>Backdrops</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the bottom before :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
```

(The collapsible feature relies on a initialization by jQuery)

Comment: That doesnt seem to fix the issue. I had it in before and just readded it. same result.

Comment: You have an jQuery version which is too old. Try this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Working pen based on your code, only added my jQuery snippet and updated jQuery version:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdvKbe

Comment: Can't believe I didn't catch that! Thanks so much!